# Rust fs read dir

Tags: rust

I am writing a program that read dir and then if there a dir it should read it

I have tried this code:

```
pub async fn list_folder() {
    let program_data_folder = String::from(std::env::var("ProgramData").expect("err") + "/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs");
    let path = Path::new(&program_data_folder);
    let paths = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap();

    for folder in paths {
        println!("Name: {}", folder.unwrap().path().display());
        if folder.unwrap().path().is_dir() {
            fs::read_dir(folder.unwrap().file_name()).unwrap();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
use of moved value: `folder`
value used here after moverustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
listeners.rs(15, 37): `folder` moved due to this method call
listeners.rs(15, 30): help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
listeners.rs(14, 9): move occurs because `folder` has type `Result<DirEntry, std::io::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
result.rs(1106, 19): `Result::<T, E>::unwrap` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `folder`
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Read the compiler errror, try what it sais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the last line:

> `Result::<T, E>::unwrap` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `folder`

After you unwrap a `Result` it's not usable any more because the `Ok` value's been moved out. That means you can't call `unwrap()` repeatedly.

To fix it, call `unwrap()` once and save the result, like so:

```
for folder in paths {
    let folder = folder.unwrap();
    println!("Name: {}", folder.path().display());
    if folder.path().is_dir() {
        fs::read_dir(folder.file_name()).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Unwrapping everything is a bad habit, though. It means I/O errors crash the program immediately. It's a lot better to let errors propagate to the caller so it can deal with them however it chooses. This entails making your function return a `Result` and replacing all the unwraps with `?`. Rust makes the best option, `?`, the shortest, to encourage good error handling.

```
pub async fn list_folder() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let program_data_folder = String::from(std::env::var("ProgramData").expect("err") + "/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs");
    let path = Path::new(&program_data_folder);
    let paths = fs::read_dir(path)?;

    for folder in paths {
        let folder = folder?;
        println!("Name: {}", folder.path().display());
        if folder.path().is_dir() {
            fs::read_dir(folder.file_name())?;
        }
    }
    
    Ok(())
}
```